# How can you make Lumen talk to a local Laravel installation?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Let's say I have a Laravel installation in a subfolder of a Lumen root. I want that all POST requests to Lumen are passed through to the Laravel installation.

What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking to use Guzzle to proxy the incoming request, but I feel there should be a better way to do this... Is it possible to reach Laravel using a server command (since they're on the same server, only by one folder level separated)?

Comment: i dont realy get this, but try to make a seperate folders foreach! and serve both sepertly and then use what you want to post to lumen (curl or whatever)

Comment: The question is, what do you want to achieve? I believe there is a better way to do this...

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a single entry point through Lumen for an API built with Laravel. Lumen should cache all GET requests, resulting in a performance gain for those.